# General Path To Downloads Folder

Tags: java, file, unix, download

I have a DownloadTask class in java that takes a filename and URL, downloads that file and saves it to the downloads folder.

To save it to *my* downloads folder, I have the line

`File file = new File("/users/myName/Downloads" + fileName + ".txt");`

What can I replace this path with so that anyone can run the program and the file will be saved to *their* downloads folder?

Comment: For Linux and similar systems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250118/using-xdg-directory-specification-on-java-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get system user documents, pictures, music folders independent of OS using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896610/how-can-i-get-system-user-documents-pictures-music-folders-independent-of-os-u)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java). 
Use...

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(home+"/Downloads/" + fileName + ".txt");
```

Comment: This is actually not a reliable way to get the Downloads folder in Windows, because users can change the folder (so that it is *not* under their home directory anymore). See here: https://blog.samirhadzic.com/2018/03/01/get-the-user-download-folder-path/

Comment: Composing a path string with "/" may not work on platforms with a different separator character.   Use this instead: File f = new File(new File(home, "Downloads"), fileName + ".txt);

Answer (score 4):

Your own folder is accessible using the $HOME environment variable.

In Java, you can find you home folder using the `user.home` system property. See [Java system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

e.g.:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```