# Download user selected file/upload a file to a user selected directory both with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, download, upload

I want to download user selected files with primefaces. I was able to do so for a specific file as described in the primface showcase for "file Download". But what I actually want is, that after pressing the "download Button" a file dialog should open, so the user can select a file for himself to download. Is that possible?

My current code for a specific file download lokks like this:

```
    public void handleLanguageFileDownload() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

        File fileToDownload = new File(DataManager.configreader.getLang_source());
        String fileName = fileToDownload.getName();
        String contentType = ec.getMimeType(fileName);
        int contentLength = (int) fileToDownload.length();

        ec.responseReset(); 
        ec.setResponseContentType(contentType); 
        ec.setResponseContentLength(contentLength); 
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""); 

        OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

        Files.copy(fileToDownload.toPath(), output);

        fc.responseComplete(); 
}
```

I want the exact same behaviour for file upload, so the user can select the folder to upload files to for himself. My current implementation uploads the file only to a specific folder.

My current code for uploading files to a specific folder looks like this:

```
    public void handleLanguageFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

        if (!this.role.canManageLanguage){
            return;
        }

        String [] filePathParts =     DataManager.configreader.getLang_source().split("/");
        String uploadPathString = DataManager.configreader.getLang_source().replaceAll(filePathParts[filePathParts.length - 1],""); //event.getFile().getFileName()
        File uploadPath = new File(uploadPathString);
        File fileToUpload = new File(uploadPath, event.getFile().getFileName());

        try (InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream()) {
            if(event.getFile().getFileName().equals(filePathParts[filePathParts.length - 1])) { //fileToUpload.getName()
            Files.copy(input, fileToUpload.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            uiManager.userMessage.info (event.getFile().getFileName() + " " + this.translate("msg_has_been_uploaded") + " !");
            this.getOwnTreeVersion();
            }
            else {
                uiManager.userMessage.error (event.getFile().getFileName() + " " + this.translate("msg_is_wrong_cannot_be_uploaded") +": " + filePathParts[filePathParts.length - 1] + " !");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: i've done something like that (give the user the opportunity to select a file) is that what you are looking for ?!?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do! Would be very nice, if you could help me out! Thanks!!!

Comment: it's a very complexe solution and understand that stackoverflow isn't here to give you a solution i will try to explain you how to do it

Comment: Do you work with `Spring` ?!?

Comment: No I don't work with Spring.

Comment: do you understand what i want to do ?!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

working with file chooser is only possible with the Upload method look at this post to understand how to implement it in your project [Upload File Step by Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964) and you can even read more in the Primefaces web site [Primefaces Upload File](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) if you need to add a `FileSizeLimite` and many other features.

Now for the download method i told you that it's impossible because you have a default file location (generally it's Download) you can read more about it in the Primefaces web site [Primefaces Download File](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) you can set it manually but it will not be dynamic look at this post [Change Download Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416365/general-path-to-downloads-folder).

Comment: did you see this ?!?

Comment: hey, yeah I just saw it and thank you very much for your response, but this is too much for what I need.

Comment: I need the webb app to just open a dialog similar to a JFileChooser, so I can choose files, choose files and save them to a directory of my choice, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Ok see this post and tell me is it what do you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964

Comment: like it is in primefaces upload file is it true

Comment: yes exactly like it is in primefaces upload file, but before i upload a file, i want to choose where exactly to upload the file (client side of course). And i want to be able to use the same dialog from upload to choose a file to download. is that possible?

Comment: look at the post that i gave to you for upload it's sure that you can do something like that but for download (i mean choose the file download location) i don't think so i will edit my answer OK

Comment: please make it a solution if it's the case

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it indeed solved my problem