# Download document through link from documetum in opencmis

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis, cmis-workbench

Is it possible to get the Link of document from my documentum repositry and access it in my android application. I got some stuff where it is shown that you can read content with the help of **ContentStream**, but the thing is I want the url of particular document and download it in my app.

I found this in stackoverflow but it was not useful -[Download Document from alfresco using opencmis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418224/download-document-from-alfresco-using-opencmis)

Please help me out with this, Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`Document.getContentUrl()`](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Document.html#getContentUrl--) method.

Comment: Through this url is it possible to download the particular document and how we can do it.