# After creating a File, how do I make sure it getting downloaded to the default download folder?

Tags: scala, file, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying out @tototoshi's [scala-csv](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv) library and its very simple, looks like this:

```
def downloadFile = Action {
    val f = new File("out.csv")
    val writer = CSVWriter.open(f)
    writer.writeAll(List(List("a", "b", "c"), List("d", "e", "f")))
    writer.close()
    Ok.sendFile(f, inline = false, _ => f.getName)
  }
```

but now I the file is getting download to my project directory:

[image]

and I want it to get downloaded to the default download folder of whoever use this func, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> the file is getting download to my project directory

This has nothing to do with Scala or with scala-csv, it's just the way `new File(String)` constructor works: if you pass a relative path like `"out.csv"` (or more generally, `"directory/directory/..."`), it uses the working directory, which is set by the "run configuration" when running in IDEA. Use an absolute path (`"C:/directory/..."` on Windows or `"/directory/..."` on Linux/Mac) instead.

> to the default download folder

There is no built-in way to find default download folder in Java, it depends on the OS. See [General Path To Downloads Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416365/general-path-to-downloads-folder) for an answer for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to resolve the download folder yourself. The library will, given a path, write a CSV to that path. It'll include other CSV facilities, but definitely not path resolving code.

To the best of my knowledge, there's no *one* environment variable that will point to default "Downloads" directories...

If you're on *nix, typically downloads are in `~/Downloads`, so your path will be `"~/Downloads".replace("~", System.getProperty("user.home"))`. This can then be passed into `java.io.File`'s constructor.

I don't know Windows' filesystem well enough to tell you if this will work for Windows as well, but a [cursory search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17436/windows-internet-explorer-download-files-from-web) suggests it should work, too.